# Deep Roots...:)

Tags: exponentiation, real-numbers

Why is it that powers with very small fractional or decimal exponents all tend to one?

That is, for $x \ll 1$, $a^x \approx 1$, seemingly. True, or untrue? Can anyone offer more explanation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $a^0=1$ for $a\neq 0$.  Exponentiation is continuous.  Hence the statement you give.

Comment: @Hayden: you need $a \gt 0$ to say "exponentiation is continuous" unless you want to get into complex numbers.

Comment: Congratulations, you've just discovered limits!

Comment: @Henry Yes, I should have been a little more clear, but thought it was implicit given one of the tags for the question is "real-numbers".  But yes, $x\mapsto a^x$ is continuous for $a\in(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you all above for your answers. Hayden's first response shows it to me clearest, however; the exponents I were thinking of were all positive and near zero, which, naturally, lead to powers near unity. This makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuitively, it's like taking a square root with a very big index. For instance, take $100^{0.00001}=100^\frac{1}{100000}=\sqrt[100000]{100}$

This means we are looking for a number that elevated to the 100.000th power equals 100.

Notice that elevating a number $n\lt1$ to a positive exponent $x\gt1$  actually outputs a smaller number than the given one.

For this reason, the number must be bigger than $1$, but small enough that elevating it to the 100.000th power (and that is *definitely* a lot: $2^{100000}$ has about $10^{30100}$ digits) will only output 100.

Specularly, the same thing happens if $a\lt1$, but $a^x$ will approach $1$ from below. Since rooting $a$ actually gives a bigger output than $a$ that is smaller than $1$, increasing the index of the root will make the output tend to $1$.

Hope this example helped. Write in the comments if you need clarifications.

Comment: Looking back on this after some time, I find this really interesting on a number of different levels. I've chosen your answer, bharb. I find your insight in the second-to-last paragraph especially nice.